# C - malloc array in function and then access array from outside

Tags: c

Here is how I malloc an int var and then access this var outside of the function

```
int f1(int ** b) {
  *b = malloc(sizeof(int)); 
  **b = 5;
}

int main() {
  int * a;
  f1(&a);
  printf("%d\n", *a);
  // keep it clean : 
  free(a);
  return 0;
}
```

Using same logic above, how do I malloc a 1 dim array inside a function and then access it outside of the func?

Please help, I am bit confused with pointers to array.

Comment: Ye gads! Why not `int* f1(int size)` and *return* the pointer? That is rather more idiomatic, especially as you are not using the return value in the above.

Comment: @dmckee: can you please write full code? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In exactly the same way but with some different arithmetic. You can think of what you are doing now as allocating an array with one element. Just multiply `sizeof(int)` by the number of elements you want your array to have:

```
int f1(int ** b, int arrsize) {
  *b = malloc(sizeof(int) * arrsize);

  // then to assign items:
  (*b)[0] = 0;
  (*b)[1] = 1;
  // etc, or you can do it in a loop
}

int main() {
  int * a, i;
  int size = 20;

  f1(&a, size); // array of 20 ints

  for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
      printf("%d\n", a[i]); // a[i] is the same as *(a + i)
                            // so a[0] is the same as *a

  // keep it clean : 
  free(a);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: how do I assign values to array inside f1?

Comment: @ihtus like this: `(*b)[x] = y`, where `x` is the index, such as `0` for the first item, `1` for the second item, and so on, and `y` is the item that you want to assign to that index. I added an example to my post.

Comment: @Seth I had a questions. If i want to return a character array of a fixed size from a function then is it better to allocate memory for that array outside the function then pass the pointer or just allocate the array inside the function then return the pointer to the array. (in terms of best programming practices)

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there `*b = malloc(sizeof(int));` allocates space for a single int ( a bit pointless since the pointer is at least as big as this)

The more normal usage is  `*b = malloc(number_of_ints*sizeof(int));`

Remember that the `[]` syntax just does the array maths for you   `(a+10)` and `a[10]` point to exactly  the same thing memory location, so you can allocate it using malloc, pass the poitner and refer to it as an array.

The only things about arrays and pointers that is complicated (apart from remembering when to use * and &) is that malloc() works in bytes, so you need to tell it the sizeof an int. But the `int *` it returns knows about ints so to get to the next value you only need to do `a++` or `a+1` or `a[1]` even though it is really 4 or 8 bytes different in value.

Comment: `a+10` and `a[10]` are not the same, but `*(a+10)` and `a[10]` are.

Comment: @Dan - good point, best to be precisely correct when teaching somebody new.

Comment: Actually if you're being pedantic, `a++` won't get you to the next element like `a+1` or `a[1]` will, you need `++a` for that :)

Answer (score 2):

*(untested, but I believe it'll work)*

```
int f1(int ** b) {
  *b = malloc(sizeof(int)*4); 

  (*b)[0] = 5;
  (*b)[1] = 6;
  (*b)[2] = 7;
  (*b)[3] = 8;
}

int main() {
  int * a;
  f1(&a);
  printf("%d %d %d %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]); // should be "5 6 7 8"
  // keep it clean : 
  free(a);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: is (*b)[0] = 5 is the only way to assign values? Below Dan used *b = 5; b[1] = 6; *(b + 2) = 7; but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I believe you could also do *((*b)+1) = 6;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `malloc()`ing a single int, `malloc` the array.

```
int f1(int * b) {
  b = malloc(ARRAY_LENGTH * sizeof(int)); 
  *b = 5;
  b[1] = 6;
  *(b + 2) = 7;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that'll work.   You don't have enough de-references on b.   So when this function returns, the memory is still allocated, but the variable in the parent-scope no longer points to allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a `calloc` call instead of `malloc` (See this: http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/calloc/)

Comment: Not necessary. malloc works just fine. You only need calloc if you want it zero-filled, which usually is only necessary for strings.

Comment: On unix systems they are the same, on other systems why do you want the expense of setting all the values to zero if you don't need to ?