# Why linked list is not printing in main function?

Tags: c, list

Here in the main function, CreateList function creates a linked list, and Printlist function prints the list.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Node{
int Element;
struct Node *Next;
};
typedef struct Node *PtrToNode;

void PrintList( PtrToNode L ) {
PtrToNode P = L->Next;
printf("head -> ");

while( P != NULL ) {
printf("%d -> ", P->Element);
P = P->Next;
}
printf("NULL\n");
}

void Insert( int X, PtrToNode P ){
PtrToNode TmpCell = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
TmpCell->Element = X;
TmpCell->Next = P->Next;
P->Next = TmpCell;
}

PtrToNode CreateList(int a[], int n){
int i;
PtrToNode header = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
PtrToNode P= header;
header->Element = -1;
header->Next = NULL;

for(i=0; i<n; i++){
Insert(a[i], P);
P = P->Next;
}

return header;
}

void ReverseList( PtrToNode L1);

void main(){
int data1[]={3,18,7,21,4,14,10,8,12,17};

PtrToNode list = CreateList(data1, 10);

printf("original list: ");PrintList(list);
ReverseList(list);

printf("revsered list: ");PrintList(list);
}


void ReverseList( PtrToNode L1){
int i;
int array[10];

for(i=9; L1->Next != NULL; i--){
L1=L1->Next;
array[i]=L1->Element;
}

L1 = CreateList(array, 10);
printf("revsered list: ");PrintList(L1);

}
```

To reverse the list, I copied the elements into array and reversed it. Then created a new linked list calling the Createlist function. No problem there. It outputs correctly. But it is supposed to print the new list in Void main() function. Why it is not printing?

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Please use more lines, but fewer empty ones.

Comment: @DivyaMamgai Good edit, sorry that mine trumped yours.

Comment: You have `L1=L1->Next;` before `array[i]=L1->Element;` and so skip the first element.

Comment: @Yunnosch no issues, just wanted the community to better understand the code :)

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: Since your implementation detail is a bit lacking at this point I'm guessing here, I recommend you going through this question which I believe is what you are after here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437791/c-malloc-array-in-function-and-then-access-array-from-outside

Comment: I reversed the list in ReverseList(), it prints the result in ReverseList(), no problem there. My question is why not printing in main function? Since pointer is involved.

Comment: updated*** please check again. I am new here .___.

Comment: Additional to my previous comment, `L1->Next != NULL` is the wrong end condition and so you skip the data in the last element of the linked list. You should check that *after* you use its data. Your method of parsing the linked list is poor: the idiomatic way is `while(ptr != NULL) { ... ptr = ptr->next; }`

Comment: ... and you have not changed `list` in `main` so that list is no different to the original when printed again.

Answer (score 1):

To Understand the cause, lets break the problem.

**main function**

```
void main(){
        ...     
        PtrToNode list = CreateList(data1, 10); // this will create the linked list and list will point to the list, let's say ** list contains the address x **.

        ...
        ReverseList(list);// list is passed to the function, ** list has address x **

        printf("revsered list: ");PrintList(list); // list is being printed again, ** what would list contains, ofcourse, x **.
}
```

**reverse function**

```
   void ReverseList( PtrToNode L1){ // L1 is pointing to list, so far so good.
            ...

            L1 = CreateList(array, 10); // L1 is overitten with address of new list. Now L1 and list in main() are not same anymore.

            printf("revsered list: ");PrintList(L1); // since L1 is new list i.e. a list created with reverse data,  hence it gave the correct output. Thing to note here is that new reverse list L1 and old list(create in main()) has no link and they are independent list.
    }
```

**How to get desired result?**

**changes required in main function**

```
void main(){
        ...
        PtrToNode list = CreateList(data1, 10);

        ...
        list  = ReverseList(list); // Update the list pointer with the reverse list.
}
```

**Changes required in Reverse function**

```
PtrToNode  ReverseList( PtrToNode L1); // change funtion to return a list pointer instead of being void.

PtrToNode ReverseList( PtrToNode L1){
       ...
        L1 = CreateList(array, 10);
        ...
        return L1; // return reverse list pointer

}
```

**SPOILER ALERT!**

Above code is subject to memory leaks!!!