# Pass array of strings to function and use malloc

Tags: c, malloc

In C Language, I try to create an array of strings, in a function with malloc.
Instead of returning the array, I pass its address and a size_t variable address.
I would like to keep the array dynamic, which means the size of the array is decided in the function.
The idea is the same as the following link, but this time with strings instead of integers : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8437818/5036990

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const int NB_ELEMENTS = 2;
const int MAX_STRING = 50;

void get_string_array(char **arr, size_t *arr_len) {

    arr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * NB_ELEMENTS);
    if (!arr) {
        printf("the memory could not be allocated for the array\n");
        return;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < NB_ELEMENTS; i++) {
        arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (MAX_STRING + 1));
        if (!arr[i]) {
            free(arr);
            printf("the memory could not be allocated for element [%d]\n", i);
        }
    }

    strcpy(arr[0], "hello");
    strcpy(arr[1], "world");
    printf("[inside the function] %s %s\n", arr[0], arr[1]);

    *arr_len = NB_ELEMENTS;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *x_array;
    size_t x_length;
    get_string_array(&x_array, &x_length);

    for (int i=0; (size_t)i < x_length; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", x_array[i]);
        free(x_array[i]);
    }
    free(x_array);

    return 0;
}
```

The code is not working, I think the issue comes from the way I declare the pointer and pass it to the function. The way the array is build should be fine.

Here's the stacktrace from gcc :

```
test-array-str.c:39:15: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
      printf("%s\n", x_array[i]);
              ~^     ~~~~~~~~~~
              %d
test-array-str.c:40:21: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘free’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         free(x_array[i]);
              ~~~~~~~^~~
In file included from test-array-str.c:2:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:563:25: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 extern void free (void *__ptr) __THROW;
                   ~~~~~~^~~~~
```

Comment: The very first line of your function discards the argument.  Perhaps you meant `*arr = malloc ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x_array[i]` is supposed to point to a dynamically allocated array of `char`, and `x_array` is supposed to point to a dynamically allocated array of `char *`, so `x_array` should be declared as `char **x_array`.

You are passing a pointer to `x_array` as the `arr` parameter of the `get_string_array` function, so the `arr` parameter should be declared as `char ***arr`.

The `get_string_array` function ignores the passed in value of the `arr` parameter, so the `x_array` variable in `main` remains unchanged by the function.

If `malloc` fails, the `get_string_array` function may be using a freed pointer in the next iteration of the loop after calling `free(arr)`. Also, `main` currently has no way to know whether `get_string_array` allocated the memory successfully or not.  One way to do that would be to set `*arr_len = 0` and `*arr = NULL` on failure.

Here is a corrected version of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const int NB_ELEMENTS = 2;
const int MAX_STRING = 50;

void get_string_array(char ***arr, size_t *arr_len) {
    int i;

    *arr_len = 0; /* in case of failure */
    *arr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * NB_ELEMENTS);
    if (!*arr) {
        printf("the memory could not be allocated for the array\n");
        return;
    }


    for (i = 0; i < NB_ELEMENTS; i++) {
        (*arr)[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (MAX_STRING + 1));
        if (!(*arr)[i]) {
            printf("the memory could not be allocated for element [%d]\n", i);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i < NB_ELEMENTS) {
        /* Failed to allocate an element. Clean up. */
        while (i > 0) {
            i--;
            free((*arr)[i]);
        }
        free(*arr);
        *arr = NULL;
        return;
    }

    strcpy((*arr)[0], "hello");
    strcpy((*arr)[1], "world");
    printf("[inside the function] %s %s\n", (*arr)[0], (*arr)[1]);

    *arr_len = NB_ELEMENTS;
}

int main(void)
{
    char **x_array;
    size_t x_length;
    get_string_array(&x_array, &x_length);

    for (int i=0; (size_t)i < x_length; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", x_array[i]);
        free(x_array[i]);
    }
    free(x_array);

    return 0;
}
```

The `get_string_array` function could be simplified by using a local variable to reduce the amount of pointer dereferencing and make the code more readable:

```
void get_string_array(char ***arr, size_t *arr_len) {
    int i;
    char **a;

    /* In case of failure... */
    *arr = NULL;
    *arr_len = 0;

    a = malloc(sizeof(char *) * NB_ELEMENTS);
    if (!a) {
        printf("the memory could not be allocated for the array\n");
        return;
    }


    for (i = 0; i < NB_ELEMENTS; i++) {
        a[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (MAX_STRING + 1));
        if (!a[i]) {
            printf("the memory could not be allocated for element [%d]\n", i);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i < NB_ELEMENTS) {
        /* Failed to allocate an element. Clean up. */
        while (i > 0) {
            i--;
            free(a[i]);
        }
        free(a);
        return;
    }

    strcpy(a[0], "hello");
    strcpy(a[1], "world");
    printf("[inside the function] %s %s\n", a[0], a[1]);

    *arr = a;    
    *arr_len = NB_ELEMENTS;
}
```

Alternatively, the `get_string_array` function could be changed to return a pointer to the allocated array (or `NULL` on failure), omitting the first parameter:

```
char **get_string_array(size_t *arr_len) {
    int i;
    char **a;

    /* In case of failure... */
    *arr_len = 0;

    a = malloc(sizeof(char *) * NB_ELEMENTS);
    if (!a) {
        printf("the memory could not be allocated for the array\n");
        return NULL;
    }


    for (i = 0; i < NB_ELEMENTS; i++) {
        a[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (MAX_STRING + 1));
        if (!a[i]) {
            printf("the memory could not be allocated for element [%d]\n", i);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i < NB_ELEMENTS) {
        /* Failed to allocate an element. Clean up. */
        while (i > 0) {
            i--;
            free(a[i]);
        }
        free(a);
        return NULL;
    }

    strcpy(a[0], "hello");
    strcpy(a[1], "world");
    printf("[inside the function] %s %s\n", a[0], a[1]);

    *arr_len = NB_ELEMENTS;
    return a;
}
```

Then, the call to the `get_string_array` function in `main` would need to change accordingly:

```
int main(void)
{
    char **x_array;
    size_t x_length;
    x_array = get_string_array(&x_length);

    for (int i=0; (size_t)i < x_length; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", x_array[i]);
        free(x_array[i]);
    }
    free(x_array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank very much, Ian, that helps

Answer (score 0):

`x_array[i]` has a type of `char` which is promoted to `int`.

you need to declare it as `char **` and in function as `char ***`